# Request to Youtube by beautifulsoup4 did not return body content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to get the content of a Youtube playlist. But the only thing that I recieved was its header content. I tried doing a lot of searching but none of them seemed to help me. The only clue was that there was something related to security and Youtube could not give me its html content.
Anyway, this is what I have been doing so far:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

and this is what I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-cast-api-enabled="true" lang="vi-VN">
 <head>
  <style name="www-roboto">
   @font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Italic'),local('Roboto-Italic'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xHIzc.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Regular'),local('Roboto-Regular'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxP.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:local('Roboto Medium'),local('Roboto-Medium'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc9.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:500;src:local('Roboto Medium Italic'),local('Roboto-MediumItalic'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc1CsE.ttf)format('truetype');}
  </style>
  <script name="www-roboto">
   if (document.fonts && document.fonts.load) {document.fonts.load("400 10pt Roboto", "T");document.fonts.load("500 10pt Roboto", "T");}
  </script>
  <script>
   var ytcsi = {gt: function(n) {n = (n || '') + 'data_';return ytcsi[n] || (ytcsi[n] = {tick: {},info: {}});},now: (window.performance && window.performance.timing &&window.performance.now && window.performance.timing.navigationStart) ?function() {return window.performance.timing.navigationStart +window.performance.now();} :function() {return (new Date()).getTime();},tick: function(l, t, n) {ticks = ytcsi.gt(n).tick;var v = t || ytcsi.now();if (ticks[l]) {ticks['_' + l] = (ticks['_' + l] || [ticks[l]]);ticks['_' + l].push(v);}ticks[l] = v;},info: function(k, v, n) {ytcsi.gt(n).info[k] = v;},setStart: function(s, t, n) {ytcsi.info('yt_sts', s, n);ytcsi.tick('_start', t, n);}};(function(w, d) {ytcsi.setStart('dhs', w.performance ? w.performance.timing.responseStart : null);var isPrerender = (d.visibilityState || d.webkitVisibilityState) == 'prerender';var vName = (!d.visibilityState && d.webkitVisibilityState)? 'webkitvisibilitychange' : 'visibilitychange';if (isPrerender) {ytcsi.info('prerender', 1);var startTick = function() {ytcsi.setStart('dhs');d.removeEventListener(vName, startTick);};d.addEventListener(vName, startTick, false);}if (d.addEventListener) {d.addEventListener(vName, function() {ytcsi.tick('vc');}, false);}function isGecko() {if (!w.navigator || !w.navigator.userAgent) {return false;}var ua = w.navigator.userAgent;return ua.indexOf('Gecko') > 0 &&ua.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') < 0 &&ua.indexOf('Edge') < 0 &&ua.indexOf('Trident') < 0 &&ua.indexOf('MSIE') < 0;}if (isGecko()) {var isHidden = (d.visibilityState || d.webkitVisibilityState) == 'hidden';if (isHidden) {ytcsi.tick('vc');}}var slt = function(el, t) {setTimeout(function() {var n = ytcsi.now();el.loadTime = n;if (el.slt) {el.slt();}}, t);};w.__ytRIL = function(el) 
{if (!el.getAttribute('data-thumb')) {if (w.requestAnimationFrame) {w.requestAnimationFrame(function() {slt(el, 0);});} else {slt(el, 16);}}};})(window, document);
  </script>
  <script>
   var ytcfg = {d: function() {return (window.yt && yt.config_) || ytcfg.data_ || (ytcfg.data_ = {});},get: function(k, o) {return (k in ytcfg.d()) ? ytcfg.d()[k] : o;},set: function() {var a = arguments;if (a.length > 1) {ytcfg.d()[a[0]] = a[1];} else {for (var k in a[0]) {ytcfg.d()[k] = a[0][k];}}}};
  </script>
  <script>
   ytcfg.set("ROOT_VE_TYPE", 5754);ytcfg.set("EVENT_ID", "avavXrLULonSqAG7mryYAg");
  </script>
  <script>
   window.yterr = window.yterr || true;
  </script>
  <script>
   (function(){/*

 Copyright The Closure Library Authors.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
var a={a:"content-snap-width-1",b:"content-snap-width-2",f:"content-snap-width-3"};function f(){var c=[],b;for(b in a)c.push(a[b]);return c}
function h(c){var b=f().concat(["guide-pinned","show-guide"]),d=b.length,g=[];c.replace(/\S+/g,function(e){for(var k=0;k<d;k++)if(e==b[k])return;g.push(e)});
return g}
;function l(c,b,d){var g=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0],e=h(g.className);c&&1251<=(window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth)&&(e.push("guide-pinned"),b&&e.push("show-guide"));d&&(d=(window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth)-21-50,1251<=(window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth)&&c&&b&&(d-=230),e.push(1262<=d?"content-snap-width-3":1056<=d?"content-snap-width-2":"content-snap-width-1"));g.className=e.join(" ")}
var m=["yt","www","masthead","sizing","runBeforeBodyIsReady"],n=this||self;m[0]in n||"undefined"==typeof n.execScript||n.execScript("var "+m[0]);for(var p;m.length&&(p=m.shift());)m.length||void 0===l?n[p]&&n[p]!==Object.prototype[p]?n=n[p]:n=n[p]={}:n[p]=l;}).call(this);

      try {window.ytbuffer = {};ytbuffer.handleClick = function(e) {var element = e.target || e.srcElement;while (element.parentElement) {if (/(^| )yt-can-buffer( |$)/.test(element.className)) {window.ytbuffer = {bufferedClick: e};element.className += ' yt-is-buffered';break;}element = element.parentElement;}};if (document.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('click', ytbuffer.handleClick);} else {document.attachEvent('onclick', ytbuffer.handleClick);}} catch(e) {}

    yt.www.masthead.sizing.runBeforeBodyIsReady(true,true,true);
  </script>
  <script name="scheduler/scheduler" src="/yts/jsbin/scheduler-vfl08UJUN/scheduler.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link href="/yts/cssbin/www-core-vflsWry6p.css" name="www-core" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/s/player/64dddad9/www-player.css" name="player/www-player" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/yts/cssbin/www-pageframe-vfl2-hqXw.css" name="www-pageframe" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/yts/cssbin/www-guide-vflc-Schd.css" name="www-guide" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <title>
   Âm nhạc - YouTube
  </title>
  <link href="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8" rel="canonical"/>
  <meta content="YouTube" property="og:site_name"/>
  <meta content="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8" property="og:url"/>
  <meta content="Âm nhạc - YouTube" property="og:title"/>
  <meta content="" property="og:description"/>
  <meta content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DyDfgMOUjCI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEWCKgBEF5IWvKriqkDCQgBFQAAiEIYAQ==&amp;rs=AOn4CLD3BirgIBzWnlS6MKrgePejx1p44A" property="og:image"/>  
  <meta content="168" property="og:image:width"/>
  <meta content="94" property="og:image:height"/>
  <meta content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DyDfgMOUjCI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEWCMQBEG5IWvKriqkDCQgBFQAAiEIYAQ==&amp;rs=AOn4CLBVf0gyjrwYcohzkCzQgR-xLrKa2A" property="og:image"/>  
  <meta content="196" property="og:image:width"/>
  <meta content="110" property="og:image:height"/>
  <meta content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DyDfgMOUjCI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCPYBEIoBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&amp;rs=AOn4CLASO9cTSzVvkZUXTirNgvratCdSUg" property="og:image"/>  
  <meta content="246" property="og:image:width"/>
  <meta content="138" property="og:image:height"/>
  <meta content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DyDfgMOUjCI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&amp;rs=AOn4CLBtIbpLAKY8G-Q_tDYxIqj8uAPpXQ" property="og:image"/>  
  <meta content="336" property="og:image:width"/>
  <meta content="188" property="og:image:height"/>
  <meta app-argument="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8" content="app-id=544007664" name="apple-itunes-app"/>
  <meta content="544007664" property="al:ios:app_store_id"/>
  <meta content="YouTube" property="al:ios:app_name"/>
  <meta content="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8&amp;feature=applinks" property="al:ios:url"/>
  <meta content="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8&amp;feature=applinks" property="al:android:url"/>
  <meta content="YouTube" property="al:android:app_name"/>
  <meta content="com.google.android.youtube" property="al:android:package"/>
  <meta content="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8&amp;feature=applinks" property="al:web:url"/>
  <meta content="true" property="al:web:should_fallback"/>
  <meta content="website" property="og:type"/>
  <meta content="87741124305" property="fb:app_id"/>
  <meta content="18+" property="og:restrictions:age"/>
  <meta content="summary" name="twitter:card"/>
  <meta content="@YouTube" name="twitter:site"/>
  <meta content="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8" name="twitter:url"/>
  <meta content="Âm nhạc - YouTube" name="twitter:title"/>
  <meta content="" name="twitter:description"/>
  <meta content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DyDfgMOUjCI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEWCKgBEF5IWvKriqkDCQgBFQAAiEIYAQ==&amp;rs=AOn4CLD3BirgIBzWnlS6MKrgePejx1p44A" name="twitter:image"/> 
  <meta content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DyDfgMOUjCI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEWCMQBEG5IWvKriqkDCQgBFQAAiEIYAQ==&amp;rs=AOn4CLBVf0gyjrwYcohzkCzQgR-xLrKa2A" name="twitter:image"/> 
  <meta content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DyDfgMOUjCI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCPYBEIoBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&amp;rs=AOn4CLASO9cTSzVvkZUXTirNgvratCdSUg" name="twitter:image"/> 
  <meta content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DyDfgMOUjCI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&amp;rs=AOn4CLBtIbpLAKY8G-Q_tDYxIqj8uAPpXQ" name="twitter:image"/> 
  <meta content="YouTube" name="twitter:app:name:iphone"/>
  <meta content="544007664" name="twitter:app:id:iphone"/>
  <meta content="YouTube" name="twitter:app:name:ipad"/>
  <meta content="544007664" name="twitter:app:id:ipad"/>
  <meta content="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8&amp;feature=twitter-deep-link" name="twitter:app:url:ipad"/>
  <meta content="YouTube" name="twitter:app:name:googleplay"/>
  <meta content="com.google.android.youtube" name="twitter:app:id:googleplay"/>
  <meta content="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8&amp;feature=twitter-deep-link" name="twitter:app:url:googleplay"/>
  <meta content="Âm nhạc - YouTube" name="title"/>
  <meta name="nosnippet"/>
  <link href="http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="android-app://com.google.android.youtube/http/youtube.comhttp://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="ios-app://544007664/http/youtube.comhttp://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="/manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
  <link href="https://www.youtube.com/opensearch?locale=vi_VN" rel="search" title="Tìm kiếm Video trên YouTube" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"/>
  <link href="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon-vfl8qSV2F.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <link href="/yts/img/favicon_32-vflOogEID.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32"/>
  <link href="/yts/img/favicon_48-vflVjB_Qk.png" rel="icon" sizes="48x48"/>
  <link href="/yts/img/favicon_96-vflW9Ec0w.png" rel="icon" sizes="96x96"/>
  <link href="/yts/img/favicon_144-vfliLAfaB.png" rel="icon" sizes="144x144"/>
  <meta content="#ff0000" name="theme-color"/>
  <link href="android-app://com.google.android.youtube/http/www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="ios-app://544007664/vnd.youtube/www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8" rel="alternate"/>
  <link href="/yts/cssbin/www-home-c4-vflSOyhuz.css" name="www-home-c4" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <style>
   .exp-invert-logo .hats-logo {background: no-repeat url(/yts/img/ringo/hitchhiker/logo_mini_gr
```

Thank guys

Comment: you should use selenium to get the whole content.

Comment: to add to @HumayunAhmadRajib, probably will need phantomJS or Chrome/firefox driver as well

Comment: You can use anything. It can be phantomJS or Chrome/firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_n5owy0fZQh1rzWt8QZk3iVvi8gjL7lVh8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
```

You better to use selenium when you are scraping dynamic data. Like comments on youtube.

Comment: I installed lxml and did what you said. However, the problem persistes. Maybe there is something wrong with the link. Do you have any existing project that use this library to get data from youtube please send me I will only use it as a sample.

Comment: I tried your code with a few more websites like amazon,.. but they are returning only the header content.